# what is equivalent to eclipse deployment assembly manifest entries in intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am migrating from eclipse to Intellij ,what is equivalent to eclipse properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Manifest Entries  in Intellij IDEA ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access manifest configuration in IntelliJ:

Open Module Settings > Artifacts > "+"

[image]

Manifest file properties area

*Manifest File*
The read-only field shows the name of the manifest file of the current artifact layout.

*Main Class*
In this text box, specify the fully qualified name of the class that will be used as the main-class entry of the manifest file. If necessary, click the Browse button and choose the desired main class in the Select Main Class dialog box, that opens. You can search for the main class by name or browse through the project tree.

*Class Path*
In this text box, specify the class-path attribute of the manifest.mf file. This attribute contains a space separated list of JARs that the current archive depend on. When the current archive is run as an executable JAR or on an application server, the JARs from the list are added to the classpath, thus making their classes available for classes of the currently selected archive.

*Create Manifest*
Click this button to have a missing manifest file generated, and specify the location for it in the dialog that opens.

*Use Existing Manifest*
Click this button to have an existing manifest file used and specify its location in the Specify Path dialog box, that opens.